# How can I make this more veil like? Used the cloth modifier but would like it to be more flush with the model. Similar to Greek sculptures

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation

[image] My model. I used cloth modifier.

[image]
Here is my desired look. Would I achieve this from sculpting instead? Similar to how I made the dress.

[image]
Would like some recommendations for creating the blindfold as well.

Comment: You're on the right track, the look of that veil is much more particular than simply dropping a cloth atop the model.  From there I think I would try sculpting with the cloth brush.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to follow the silhouette of my models face in sculpt mode.

Comment: Maybe try a Cloth, apply, then use a Shrinkwrap, then a Cloth, it will make the cloth stick more, then sculpt as suggested by Allen

Comment: oh shrinkwrap is a great idea